# shared-layout js loading issue while deploy ABP Boilerplate application on myasp.net

Tags: web-hosting, boilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I have deployed AbpBoilerplate ASP.NET CORE with the jQuery option.

Deployed successfully but the system is not able to find the min js files and jquery is also not able to find in shared-layout page.

[image]

Is there any bundle config I need to set?

Please let me the flow as abp is not giving any deployment steps.

Note: I am using myasp.net as hosting service.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restore the client-side libraries before you run the application.

From https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Startup-Template-Core:

> - Since it uses **libman**, go to **Web.Mvc** project. Right click to **libman.json** file. Then click to **Restore Client-Side Libraries**.
>
>   (If you are not using Visual Studio and/or you are on a mac you can use [Libman CLI](https://github.com/aspnet/LibraryManager/wiki/Using-LibMan-CLI) . After installing it while in **Web.Mvc** folder run `libman restore`)

Comment: Hi, Aaron thanks for this solution. I have done that so many times and deployed but the same issue persists.